# Azure Data Factory Event Based Trigger not working as Expected

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-triggers

Storage Explorer Version: 1.14.2
Build Number: 20200715.2
Platform/OS: Windows 10
Architecture: ia32
Regression From: Not sure

Hello All,

I have created a event based trigger for triggering some pipelines. So the issue is when i try to add csv files manually through storage explorer to designated blob location my trigger is working perfectly, but when an external source like I have a backend python code which is pushing the files into the blob location, when this is happening the event based trigger is not triggering. I just checked the content type for manual upload the content type is vnd.ms-excel and for python code based upload is octet-stream. Is the issue something related to this or any other. My Storage explorer version is 1.14.2.

Comment: Hi @SHIBASHISH TRIPATHY, please correct me if I understand you wrong in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the version of the Python SDK.
I'm using [Python v12 SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python) to upload blob to Azure blob storge and it works well.

Here is my python code:

```py
import os, uuid
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient, __version__

try:
    print("Azure Blob storage v" + __version__ + " - Python quickstart sample")
    # Quick start code goes here
    # Create the BlobServiceClient object which will be used to create a container client
    connect_str = os.getenv('AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING')
    
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_str)
    

    # Get container
    container_name = "test"     

    print(container_name)
    # Create the container
    container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
    
    
    # Create a file in local data directory to upload and download
    local_path = "./data"
    local_file_name = "Test.csv"
    upload_file_path = os.path.join(local_path, local_file_name)
    
    print(upload_file_path)
    
    # Create a blob client using the local file name as the name for the blob
    blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob=local_file_name)
    
    print("\nUploading to Azure Storage as blob:\n\t" + local_file_name)
    
    # Upload the  file
    with open(upload_file_path, "rb") as data:
        blob_client.upload_blob(data)
except Exception as ex:
    print('Exception:')
    print(ex)
```

When I use python to upload the csv file to the Azure blob storage, the event trigger triggered the pipeline running and it  works well:

[image]